# Friend status for derived classes of purely virtual class

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

I ran into the following problem and I don't really know what the best way is to approach this. I want to evaluate `expression` objects that are constructed with a `foo` object. The `expression` class and its derived classes should be allowed to access private members of foo; but except from declaring all derived classes individually as friend I don't know how I could make this work - can I declare a virtual function a friend of `foo`?

```
class foo{
public:
            foo(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
    void    addExpression(expression *e){exp.push_back(e);}
    bool    evaluateAll(){
        for(expression* e : exp){
            if(!e->evaluate())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
private:
    int a,b,c;
    std::list<expression*> exp;
};
```

The `expression` classes:

```
struct expression{
    expression(foo *f) : f(f) {}
    virtual bool evaluate() = 0;
private:
    foo *f;
};

struct anExpression : public expression{
    anExpression(foo *f) : expression(f) {}
    bool evaluate(){
        return f->a < f->b;
    }
};

struct anotherExpression : public expression{
    anotherExpression(foo *f) : expression(f) {}
    bool evaluate(){
        return f->a > f->b && f->a != f->c;
    }
};
```

The `main`function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    foo f(3,2,1);
    f.addExpression(new anExpression(&f));
    f.addExpression(new anotherExpression(&f));
    f.evaluateAll();

    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work of course but I really don't want to add every derived class of `expression` as a friend or make `expression` inherit from `foo`. Is there another solution?

Comment: Using a get-function?

Comment: Yes that would work - I also could make all the members public but that's not the point. In a way I want the `foo` object to take possession of the `expression` objects and I don't want to expose the members of `foo` either directly or via get-functions.

Comment: You could make `expression` a friend class of `foo`, and implement get-functions in `expression`.

Comment: What I would do is to make `expression` a friend of `foo` and have a `protected` function inside `expression` which gets values from `foo`.

Comment: That is definitely a better solution but I would still have to change the `expression` class every time I change `foo` - is that really the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would make `expression` a friend class of `foo`, that is, add the following to foo:

```
friend struct expression;
```

And then implement get-functions in `expression`, like so:

```
struct expression {
// other stuff

protected:
    int get_a(foo const * f) { return f->a; }
}
```

The get-functions should be marked `protected` to reduce exposure. The parameter of the get-function is `const`, for good measure.

Comment: why not simply a `foo::get_a()` ?

Comment: @tobi303 Simply because OP didn't like it... because it exposed some of the members of foo. But yes, it seemed like the quick solution.

Comment: ah sorry didnt see the comment that says `foo::get` isnt an option

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but isn't this a case for the Curiously recurring template pattern? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern